# Why would win32gui.MoveWindow() return false?

Tags: python, win32gui

I've been working on a Python program, in which I simple do not understand why using the function
win32gui.MoveWindow() returns false and prints "fail".  It seems like the parameter types are correct, (i.x, i.y, i.w, i.h all are integers). Yet, the function fails to move the Window. I'm assuming that the function returning false most likely means that it failed to move the window to the provided position. Extra note: I'm providing the hwnd of Opera.exe, if somehow that's the cause of this.

```
if win32gui.MoveWindow(hwnd, int(i.x), int(i.y), int(i.w), int(i.h), True):
    print("scs")
else:
    print("fail")
```

I wonder why. I've used a for loop to loop through an array of custom class objects, (which is "i"), and the class is this:

```
class window(object):
def __init__(self, process):
    self.x = 0
    self.y = 0
    self.w = 0
    self.h = 0
    self.process = process
```

And the hwnd I'm providing as the parameter isn't invalid either, as I'm
using win32gui.EnumWindows(fixWindows, None) where "fixWindows" is the function name. I've tried debugging the title of these hwnd's, and they don't seem wrong.
Thanks!

Edit: This function also didn't work as required.

Comment: As per your code, the width and height of the window is 0. Not an expert but a window with width and height equal to 0 does not seem right. Does the code work when width and height is not equal to 0 ? May be worth trying.

Comment: @sri Good point.
But, I tried replacing "int(i.w), int(i.h)" with "100, 100" but it still made no difference.